# The default font for Multiline Textbox is different from singleline Textbox?

Tags: asp.net, fonts, textbox

I have couple of Textbox controls in my page. Some are multilines and others are singleline. I notice the default fonts between multilines and singleline Textboxes are different. Anybody knows why? How do I make them the same font? Thanks.

Here is the sample:

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">hello</asp:TextBox>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine">hello</asp:TextBox>
```

The font for TextBox1 is MS Shell Dlg, the font for TextBox2 is monospace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Style Selector for CSS**

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">

    /* match all single/multiline textboxes (IE 7+ for the attribute selector) */
    TEXTAREA, INPUT[type="text"]
    {
        /* font size, line height, face */
        font: 11px/1.5 "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;

        /* useful for supporting 100% width inclusive of padding and border */
        box-sizing: border-box; 
    }

</style>
```

Note that the `media` attribute is not required but the behavior of input fields can vary widely depending on the rendering target (e.g. printer versus screen). For screen media, the style should encourage input; for print, the style may be different since a printed page is (obviously) not editable.

As to "why" the default fonts are different, `TEXTAREAs` were historically sized using columns and rows. A fixed-width font (like monospace) makes it possible to control the number of characters in a row, which is probably why most browsers use a fixed-width font for the `TEXTAREA` by default.

**Assigning a CSS Class via a Theme (ASP.NET only)**

In your theme file, add an entry in the following manner:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="myClassName"></asp:TextBox>
```

This will apply the class "myClassName" to all textboxes to which the theme applies.

Comment: Is it possible I apply the theme for the whole solution instead of adding it to each page?

Comment: @GaolaiPeng - Yes, it is possible via the web.config. See this link for the specific syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yy5hxdk.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Set a font style to it:
CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .text
    {
        font-family:Verdana;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<asp:TextBox  CssClass="text" ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="196px" TextMode="MultiLine" 
    Width="271px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Good luck!

Comment: This will work but placing CssClass on each textbox declaration is usually more code than is needed. Typically this can be centrally defined using only a CSS tag selector and/or an ASP.NET theme. Also, the inline height and width on the tag itself will be hard to maintain if there are many textboxes declared throughout the application.

Comment: Do you mind telling me how to use a CSS tag selector and/or an ASP.NET theme? I have no clue. We do have lots of textboxes (single line or multiline) on many different pages.

Comment: @GaolaiPeng - The CSS selector is in my answer; I also updated it to include how you would control the CSS class using a theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a style sheet, you'll need to ensure that you don't have a specific font set to your text area that differs from your single line text box.  It would look similar to the following,

```
text area
{
   font-size:10px;
}
```